# DropShadow constructor is not defined

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX, and I am following this tutorial, https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1, to become familiar with it.

I am trying to set up a DropShadow for my text, and it says the constructor is not recognized. Yet, the tutorial uses the exact line of code with no errors, and according to the DropShadow JavaDoc a constructor of this type should exist.

[Exact error that is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aga4Z.png)

NOTE: I forgot to delete the line that says "DropShadow d", but this has no effect on the rest of the application.

I attempted to create a DropShadow named 'd' on a separate line of code that followed the exact scheme of the constructor, but this did not work either.

```
    DropShadow d = new DropShadow(2,3,3,Color.RED);
    t.setEffect(d);
```

Appending zeros does not allow the constructor to recognize the values as doubles.

I'm using JDK_1.8_144 and e(fx)clipse 3.0.0.2, i.e. the latest release of each.

So, does anybody know why the DropShadow cannot be constructed?

Thanks!

```
    package myapp;

    import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class JavaFX extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    Text t = new Text("Hello FX");
    t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 60));
    t.setEffect(new DropShadow(2,3,3,Color.RED));
    p.setCenter(t);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong import for `Color`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: your import should be javafx.scene.paint.Color

Comment: Ah, this all makes sense now. I attempted to resolve that earlier by switching to java.awt.color, but that had no effect either. I should have known that javafx would have had its own import for color.

Comment: You typically should not import *anything* from awt in a JavaFX application.

Comment: Noted. All the comments are appreciated.